# Customizing Meteor account to accept additional user information

Tags: meteor, account, meteor-accounts

I'm new to meteor and react.  I successfully followed this tutorial here https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/adding-user-accounts

Now I want to customize the code created from this tutorial. I want to change the registration system so that when a user creates a new account, they need to supply the following mandatory information:

- profile picture of themselves
- valid credit card information so that I can charge them $5/month against a credit card processing gateway
- the values 1, 2 or 3 to denote which type of monthly subscription they
  would like

I'm trying to figure out to what extent Meteor's account package what I need, and for the things I can't support, what properties can I override to introduce the behaviour that I need?  Or do I need to build my own registration system from scratch?

Hopefully my question isn't too broad...I just need some direction on what is or isn't possible out of the box with Meteor accounts.

Comment: You might want to look at the [useraccounts:core][1] package and the associated [guide][2], specifically the part on extending the form template


  [1]: https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core
  [2]: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#form-fields-configuration

Comment: Don't you really just want to build your own accounts UI and add your business rules there? It sounds like you merely want a custom registration form.

Comment: @MichelFloyd ok sure.  I asked because I wasn't sure what the meteor accounts package was capable of...like if there were hooks I could place my own custom code in.  But i guess not?

Comment: You can use the [collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) package to hook the `Users` collection just like any other collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some stuff when user is created with:

```
//server
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){

if (typeof(user.services.facebook) != "undefined") {
    user.email = user.services.facebook.email;
    user.profilePicture = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture/?type=large";
    user.username = user.services.facebook.name;
    //other fields which you can also insert as '' or null
} 

if (typeof(user.services.twitter) != "undefined") {
    user.profilePicture = user.services.twitter.profile_image_url;
    user.username = user.services.twitter.screenName;
    //other fields which you can also insert as '' or null
}

if (typeof(user.services.google) != "undefined") {
    user.email = user.services.google.email;
    user.profilePicture = user.services.google.picture;
    user.username = user.services.google.name;
    //other fields which you can also insert as '' or null
}

if (typeof(user.services.password) != "undefined") {
    user.profilePicture = '/predefined-logo.png';
    //e-mail, username & password are not defined/added here 
}
return user;
});
```

Later, you can add/edit more stuff with Methods

```
Meteor.methods({
    methodName: function(userId, var1, var2) {
        Meteor.users.update(userId,{
            $set: {
                someField: var1,
                someField2: var2 
            }
        })
    }
})
```

So you could create a template with a form and update the user like ^.